# Anyone implemented language selection for Arabic & English using Metronic Keentheme with reactjs?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, internationalization, metronic

We are using Metronics keentheme template for ReactJs but no support for using Arabic & English within the same project. Two CSS files were provided for rtl and ltr version and I am trying to figure out an option that can inject either CSS files based on user language selection.

Please if anyone can suggest an alternative approach? I've raised this point with Metronic technical team and not heard from them.

We tried to add CSS files in the public folder and anchoring it along with an id attribute inside index.html, then trying to manipulate the DOM from react component on runtime to change direction of html and alter the attribute of the CSS link to point to either Arabic or English CSS based on user selection.

Setting the HTML direction works fine, but the CSS does not work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yh4yW.png)

Our objective is to customize our project having ability to switch between these CSS files for Arabic and English on runtime using reactjs.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.